# Pyspark AnalysisException Py4JJavaError on transformation withColumn()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Working with Pyspark using the withColumn() command in order to do some basic transformation on the dataframe, namely, to update the value of a column. Looking for some debug assistance while I also strudy the problem.

Pyspark is issuing an AnalysisException & Py4JJavaError on the usage of the pyspark.withColumn command.

_c49='EVENT_NARRATIVE' is the withColumn('EVENT_NARRATIVE')... reference data elements inside the spark df (dataframe).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
```

```
df = df.withColumn('EVENT_NARRATIVE', lower(col('EVENT_NARRATIVE')))
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o100.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`EVENT_NARRATIVE`' given input columns: [_c3, _c17, _c40, _c21, _c48, _c12, _c39, _c18, _c31, _c10, _c45, _c26, _c5, _c43, _c24, _c33, _c9, _c14, _c1, _c16, _c47, _c20, _c46, _c32, _c22, _c7, _c2, _c42, _c37, _c36, _c30, _c8, _c38, _c23, _c25, _c13, _c29, _c41, _c19, _c44, _c11, _c28, _c6, _c50, _c49, _c0, _c15, _c4, _c34, _c27, _c35];;
'Project [_c0#604, _c1#605, _c2#606, _c3#607, _c4#608, _c5#609, _c6#610, _c7#611, _c8#612, _c9#613, _c10#614, _c11#615, _c12#616, _c13#617, _c14#618, _c15#619, _c16#620, _c17#621, _c18#622, _c19#623, _c20#624, _c21#625, _c22#626, _c23#627, ... 28 more fields]
+- Relation[_c0#604,_c1#605,_c2#606,_c3#607,_c4#608,_c5#609,_c6#610,_c7#611,_c8#612,_c9#613,_c10#614,_c11#615,_c12#616,_c13#617,_c14#618,_c15#619,_c16#620,_c17#621,_c18#622,_c19#623,_c20#624,_c21#625,_c22#626,_c23#627,... 27 more fields] csv
```

1 row of sample data from df.head():

```
[Row(_c0='BEGIN_YEARMONTH', _c1='BEGIN_DAY', _c2='BEGIN_TIME', _c3='END_YEARMONTH', _c4='END_DAY', _c5='END_TIME', _c6='EPISODE_ID', _c7='EVENT_ID', _c8='STATE', _c9='STATE_FIPS', _c10='YEAR', _c11='MONTH_NAME', _c12='EVENT_TYPE', _c13='CZ_TYPE', _c14='CZ_FIPS', _c15='CZ_NAME', _c16='WFO', _c17='BEGIN_DATE_TIME', _c18='CZ_TIMEZONE', _c19='END_DATE_TIME', _c20='INJURIES_DIRECT', _c21='INJURIES_INDIRECT', _c22='DEATHS_DIRECT', _c23='DEATHS_INDIRECT', _c24='DAMAGE_PROPERTY', _c25='DAMAGE_CROPS', _c26='SOURCE', _c27='MAGNITUDE', _c28='MAGNITUDE_TYPE', _c29='FLOOD_CAUSE', _c30='CATEGORY', _c31='TOR_F_SCALE', _c32='TOR_LENGTH', _c33='TOR_WIDTH', _c34='TOR_OTHER_WFO', _c35='TOR_OTHER_CZ_STATE', _c36='TOR_OTHER_CZ_FIPS', _c37='TOR_OTHER_CZ_NAME', _c38='BEGIN_RANGE', _c39='BEGIN_AZIMUTH', _c40='BEGIN_LOCATION', _c41='END_RANGE', _c42='END_AZIMUTH', _c43='END_LOCATION', _c44='BEGIN_LAT', _c45='BEGIN_LON', _c46='END_LAT', _c47='END_LON', _c48='EPISODE_NARRATIVE', _c49='EVENT_NARRATIVE', _c50='DATA_SOURCE'),
 Row(_c0='201210', _c1='29', _c2='1600', _c3='201210', _c4='29', _c5='1922', _c6='68680', _c7='416744', _c8='NEW HAMPSHIRE', _c9='33', _c10='2012', _c11='October', _c12='High Wind', _c13='Z', _c14='12', _c15='EASTERN HILLSBOROUGH', _c16='BOX', _c17='29-OCT-12 16:00:00', _c18='EST-5', _c19='29-OCT-12 19:22:00', _c20='0', _c21='0', _c22='0', _c23='0', _c24='109.60K', _c25='0.00K', _c26='ASOS', _c27='55.00', _c28='MG', _c29=None, _c30=None, _c31=None, _c32=None, _c33=None, _c34=None, _c35=None, _c36=None, _c37=None, _c38=None, _c39=None, _c40=None, _c41=None, _c42=None, _c43=None, _c44=None, _c45=None, _c46=None, _c47=None, _c48='Sandy, a hybrid storm with both tropical and extra-tropical characteristics, brought high winds and coastal flooding to southern New England.  Easterly winds gusted to 50 to 60 mph for interior southern New England; 55 to 65 mph along the eastern Massachusetts coast and along the I-95 corridor in southeast Massachusetts and Rhode Island; and 70 to 80 mph along the southeast Massachusetts and Rhode Island coasts.  A few higher higher gusts occurred along the Rhode Island coast.  A severe thunderstorm embedded in an outer band associated with Sandy produced wind gusts to 90 mph and concentrated damage in Wareham early Tuesday evening, |a day after the center of Sandy had moved into New Jersey.  In general, moderate coastal flooding occurred along the Massachusetts coastline, and major coastal flooding impacted the Rhode Island coastline.  The storm surge was generally 2.5 to 4.5 feet along the east coast of Massachusetts, but peaked late Monday afternoon in between high tide cycles.  Seas built to between 20 and 25 feet Monday afternoon and evening just off the Massachusetts east coast.  Along the south coast, the storm surge was 4 to 6 feet and seas from 30 to a little over 35 feet were observed in the outer coastal waters.  The very large waves on top of the storm surge caused destructive coastal flooding along stretches of the Rhode Island exposed south coast.  ||Sandy grew into a hurricane over the southwest Caribbean and then headed north across Jamaica, Cuba, and the Bahamas.  As Sandy headed north of the Bahamas, the storm interacted with a vigorous weather system moving west to east across the United States and began to take on a hybrid structure.  Strong high pressure over southeast Canada helped with the expansion of the strong winds well north of the center of Sandy.  In essence, Sandy retained the structure of a hurricane near its center (until shortly before landfall) while taking on more of an extra-tropical cyclone configuration well away from the center.  Sandy���s track was unusual.  The storm headed northeast and then north across the western Atlantic and then sharply turned to the west to make landfall near Atlantic City, NJ during Monday evening.  Sandy subsequently weakened and moved west across southern Pennsylvania on Tuesday before turning north and heading across western New York state into Quebec during Tuesday night and Wednesday.', _c49='The Automated Surface Observing System at Manchester-Boston Regional Airport (KMHT) recorded sustained wind speeds of 38 mph and gusts to 63 mph.  In Manchester, a tree was downed on Harrison Street.  In Hudson, a tree was downed on Lawrence Road, bringing down wires that sparked a fire that damaged a house.  In Merrimack, a tree was downed, taking down wires and closing Amherst Road from Meetinghouse Road to Riverside Drive.  In Nashua, a tree was downed onto a house on Broad Street, near the Hollils line.  No structural damage was found.  Numerous trees were downed, blocking roads.', _c50='CSV')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column names are in the form of `_c` followed by a number, because presumbaly you did not specify `header=True` while reading the input file. You can do

```
df = spark.read.csv('filepath', header=True)
```

So that the column names will be `BEGIN_YEARMONTH`, `BEGIN_DAY`, ... etc, instead of `_c0`, `_c1`, ..., and then your `withColumn` code should work.

You can also consider adding `inferSchema=True` to ensure that the data types are suitable.

---

Of course, you can also stick with your current code, and do

```
df2 = df.withColumn('_c49', lower(col('_c49')))
```

But that's not a good long-term solution. Column names should be sensible, and you also don't want the header to be one of the rows in your dataframe.